# Dell xps 15 9570 dual boot windows 10 with ubuntu 18.04, serious errors

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, ahci

I have been attempting to dual boot my Dell XPS 15 9570 with Ubuntu. I turned off fast boot and changed raid on to ahci. I had the latest version of Ubuntu loaded onto my USB flash drive and I tried to install it.

The first problem I had was when trying to install ubuntu the screen froze and I could go no further. I got past this by updating my bios and switching from the raid on to ahci. However, after I managed to install ubuntu windows would not start and it kept looping around to the automatic repair tool.

Also after restarting my computer after installing ubuntu and returning to try and log in it would freeze after I logged in. So in my case, neither of the operating systems were working. I decided to give up on Ubuntu and try to fix windows.

Upon removing my USB device the grub disappeared and I was just left with windows. However, it was still stuck in this loop. I tried changing the secure boot setting in the bios however this did not work.

I ended up attempting to return the computer to factory settings however windows will not boot and it still stuck in this boot loop. Any help with either os will be greatly appreciated.

I am very up at the minute as I have just bought this laptop for college which starts in two months and I will be in big trouble if I cannot manage to fix it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/239462/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-cant-boot-into-any-of-the-os may have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already reverted all BIOS settings to factory, try using SupportAssist OS Recovery.

- Restart the laptop and press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
- Before you select any option make sure the *Boot mode* is set to *UEFI*.
- Select *SupportAssist OS Recovery* from *Other Options*.

  - First try to *Repair System issues*.
  - If you will decide to use *Restore System* option, remember to backup the files before that.

This would be the first step to try before getting into more laborious options.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problems with my XPS 9570. You may have forgotten to create a "Bootable" or "Live" USB with the 18.04 ISO. For me, Dell customer support helped me successfully factory reset. Then, I followed [these instructions](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) exactly, and the dual boot now works perfectly.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.